# get seo_category_infos in istagram

Tags: instagram

Using the **file_get_contents()** function, I was able to get only a part of the source of the Instagram page.
Can anyone suggest a way to get all Instagram sources?
Another problem is that I cannot use a URL with the letter **&** in the **file_get_contents()** function.
The error entered is the following error :

## https://example.com/?a=1 ***&*** b=1

If the original link was like this:

## https://example.com/?a=1&b=1

But it gives an error as soon as the code is executed